# Web API route to action name

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I need a controller to return JSON to be consumed by JavaScript so I inherited from the `ApiController` class but it isn't behaving as I expected.  The Apress book Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 and most of the online examples I've found give examples like:

```
public class ServicesController : ApiController
{
    public string[] MethodFruit()
    {
        return new string[] { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
}
```

accessed via the URL:

```
http://mysite/services/methodfruit
```

But that never works - the resource isn't found.  The only approach I can get working is to have the controller contain a different method for each HTTP verb, then:

```
http://mysite/api/services
```

Which calls the GET method.

I checked the Apress website but they don't seem to have any forums and the current source code is in VS 2012 which I'm not using.  I examined the source files and they seem to think the former approach should work.  Is the former approach no longer supported?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yep... generally you have to follow the default naming convention expected by ASP.NET WEB API.

Check this official doc:

[Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

If you do not want to follow the convention, you can try the *Routing by Action Name* section described in the above linked doc.

> Routing by Action Name
>
> With the default routing template, Web API uses the HTTP method to
>   select the action. However, you can also create a route where the
>   action name is included in the URI:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ActionApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );
```

In your case, you'd have to do this:

```
[HttpGet]
public string[] MethodFruit()
{
    return new string[] { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
}
```

Comment: I have done the same thing. But I want to get this function called on `POST` request. I have added `{action}` in route and added `[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` instead of `[HttpGet]`. But It says 404 when accessing this API by making a post request. When no issue with `GET`. My action name is `GetAuthToken`. I am really can't get this resolved. Please help.

Comment: @shashwat check if this solves your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12766431/114029

Comment: @LenielMacaferi I am already using `[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]`. Please look on http://pastebin.com/aCJStvT7

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this in Web API. Anyways, check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050689/114029 Here we see a guy doing exactly that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19765210/114029

Answer (score 10):

Adding additional information on above answer. Adding **RoutePrefix** would fix the issue sometimes. Hope it helps
 
 **Controller**

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/Services")]
    public class ServicesController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [Route("MethodFruit")]
        public string[] MethodFruit()
        {
            return new string[] { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        }
    }
```

In config

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "ActionApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );
```

Comment: Using [RoutePrefix("api/referencedata")] and [Route("products")] on the action method was the only thing that worked for me.  Fails when I used [Route("api/referencedata")][ActionName("products")]

Answer (score 8):

If you want Web API to look for the action name when routing, change the WebApiConfig.cs class in the App_Start folder to this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then you can just make a GET request to

```
http://mysite/api/Services/MethodFruit
```

Comment: I'd missed the WebApiConfig.cs class entirely.  It makes a lot more sense now - I wondered why the RouteConfig class hadn't changed...

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue, i found that on my code

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

i've imported  Mvc intead of using System.Web.Http.
so it was using Mvc routing not webApi route.
i've replaced that with

```
using System.Web.Http
```

and it works for me. i'm adding my answer so newbies won't repeat the same mistake