# Ajax Jquery Request with WEB API

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to retrieve a JSON result from a WEB API call.

My WEP API method:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public object GetTest()
    {
         rep = new ChatRepository();
        chatBoxCLS box = rep.Chatrequest(chatRequestLevel.Parent, null);

        System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult jsonResult = new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult
        {
            Data = box,
            JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };


        return jsonResult.Data;
    }
```

I have modified the WebapiConfig.cs as below, so that it will always return JSON

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
          );

            var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

Below is my Jquery ajax call:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:6606/api/values/GetTest',

            dataType: 'json',

            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (msg) {

                alert('success');

            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {

                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

It's always end up in error alert. no data is received from the WEB API. I tried debugging and found that my request successfully hits the WEB API method and return JSON. Below is the JSON data it returns.

> {"listOfItems":[{"id":14,"description":"New
>   test","display_number":1},{"id":4,"description":"operational","display_number":2},{"id":3,"description":"sales","display_number":3},{"id":5,"description":"technical","display_number":4}],"reply":null,"history":null,"Initialhistory":null,"Question":"","chatids":null,"displayNum":null}

why am i not getting any result on client side?

Comment: I think it's because you are only returning the `Json Data` not including the `JsonRequestBehavior` making it not work on get request?

Comment: @WannaCSharp i tried with  return new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult()
            {
                Data = jsonResult.Data,
                JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            }; but did not work

Comment: Can you try looking at the browser console if it gives any errors?

Comment: i get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:6606/api/values/Get. Origin http://localhost:7599 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." error but i think it's ignorable because my POST request worked even thogh i got that error

Comment: I would hesitate to ignore that error. It's a pretty clear CORS problem, you need to setup your WebAPI to return the correct CORS headers. stackoverflow.com/questions/19762027/ajax-jquery-request-with-web-api

Comment: @StephenByrne you are correct and that was exactly the issue. I have added my solution as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to response header

```
public class CrossDomainActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            bool needCrossDomain = true;

            if (needCrossDomain)
            {
                actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            }

            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        }
    }


[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[CrossDomainActionFilter]
    public object GetTest()
    {
         rep = new ChatRepository();
        chatBoxCLS box = rep.Chatrequest(chatRequestLevel.Parent, null);

        System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult jsonResult = new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult
        {
            Data = box,
            JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };


        return jsonResult.Data;
    }
```