# ASP.Net MVC Web Api Function returning error for entirely different call

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Api Controller:

```
public class FamilyController : ApiController
{
    ApplicationDb db = new ApplicationDb();

    public IEnumerable<Family> GetFamilies()
    {
        return db.Families.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(n => n.FamilyName);
    }

    public Family GetFamily(int id)
    {
        return db.Families.AsNoTracking().Single(n => n.FamilyID == id);
    }
}
```

The following javascript file called functions.js

```
(function () {
window.dbApp = window.dbApp || {};

// Private: Routes
var familiesUrl = function () { return "/api/family/getfamilies" },
    familyUrl = function (id) { return "/api/family/getfamily?id=" + id };

// Private: Ajax helper
function ajaxRequest(type, url, data) {
    var options = { dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json", cache: false, type: type, data: ko.toJSON(data) }
    return $.ajax(url, options);
}

// Public: Methods
window.dbApp.Db = {
    getFamilies: function() {
        return ajaxRequest("get",familiesUrl());
    },
    getFamily: function (id) {
        return ajaxRequest("get", familyUrl(id));
    },
};

})();
```

And the following javascript on a view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/functions")    
<script type="text/javascript">
    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.Families = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.Init = function () {
            dbApp.Db.getFamilies()
                .done(function (data) {
                    self.Families(data);
                });
        };

        self.Init();
    }

    var model = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model);
</script>
```

But I get the following error returned: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'MadcapsPortal.Models.Family GetFamily(Int32)' in 'MadcapsPortal.Controllers.FamilyController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

It's like it's calling the wrong function.  What's strange is that another page that uses the following works fine??

```
var passedId = @ViewBag.PassedID;
    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.Family = ko.observable();
        self.FamilyName = ko.observable();

        self.Init = function() {
            dbApp.Db.getFamily(passedId)
                .done(function(data){
                    self.Family(data);
                    self.FamilyName(data.FamilyName);                        
                });
        };

        self.Init();
    }

    var model = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use the follwing URL's:

1. For the list resource use `GET /api/family`
2. For the resource by Id use `GET /api/family/2` or `GET /api/family?id=2`

Please read this for more information on ASP.NET Web API routing:

- http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions
- [Web API route to action name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661946/web-api-route-to-action-name)

**But basically:** The URL to action method mapping will mainly be determined my the HTTP method and patterns in your action method names and the methods' signatures. `GET /api/family` will be mapped to a method named somewhat like *get* and containing no further parameters.

Comment: There will be more Actions within the controller so need action name, thank you for the reminder on changing the routes however I have added this:
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
And made no difference.

Comment: Scratch that, changed the default api instead and working, thanks.